# limit of a function involving infinite nested roots

Tags: limits

I was given the following problem :
 $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}}$$

The following is my approach:

$= \sqrt{ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}} } $

I divide by x:

$= \sqrt{ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}{x}} } $

I then reasoned that obviously:
$ \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}<x$
that is  $ \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}{x}  = \frac{1}{x^y} : y>0 $
hence  $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}{x} =0$

I concluded that the original limit equals $ \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+0}} = 1$

Was my reasoning correct? And is this a legitimate mathematical approach to solve this limit?

Comment: You should use \cdots for dots between plus signs, use \dots for dots between commas.

Comment: The denominator has a closed form if you are interested: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadical.html

Comment: Going from $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \cdots}} < x$ to deciding that it must be polynomial in $x$ is invalid

Comment: Actually, there's a simpler approach for this: Let $y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}$, $y^2-x=y$, $\sqrt x=\sqrt{y^2-y}$. So $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}}=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt {y^2-y}}{y}=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}y}=1$

Comment: The "obviously" part needs to be proved, in fact you assume without proof more, that the limit of the ratio is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You could have taken this approach as well:

$$A=\sqrt{x+\sqrt { x+\sqrt {x+...}}}$$

$$A^2=x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt { x+\sqrt {x+...}}}=x+A$$

$$A^2-A=x$$

$$A^2-A+\frac14=x+\frac14$$

$$(A-\frac12)^2=x+\frac14$$

$$A=\sqrt{x+\frac14}+\frac12$$

then the limit becomes

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\frac14}+\frac12}$$

Which is indeed 1

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is well defined?

Comment: How can I prove that this limit equals 1 ?

Comment: $\sqrt{x+\frac14}+\frac12$ is asymptotic to $\sqrt x$ for large x. So the limit equals 1.